# Disable the Business Account Toggle button On Person Account Edit page

Tags: account, person-accounts

I have a query regarding the Account .. I have a Customize Vf page  and i want that whenever the user edit the person account page then the business account page button should be disable and Vice versa.
**Note:-Disable  should be only in the edit Mode  page .**
Is there anybody who worked over it ? Please help me Out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming person account button and the business account button are complete custom buttons.
if that is the thing.
Maintain two boolean values in you controller which are true when page loads.
When you click on the person Account button pass false as a pram  to the business account button. similarly do the same with the business account btn click.

With the info provided in the question I gave this approach.